# Finding duplicates in an array using while loop, and add the sum of the duplicate elements

Tags: python, arrays

I used the for loop code found on the internet but my professor asked me to convert it to while loop. I also don't have any idea how to code the sum part. We can't use any advanced stuff like def. I only started to code for class using python and I've honestly been stuck and haven't been catching up on the lessons. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
import array as arr
a=arr.array('i', [])
x=0

#size of array
arrsize=int(input("\nPlease Enter the number of elements: "))

#elements
print("\nPlease Enter "+str(arrsize)+" elements")
while(x<arrsize):
    num=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    a.insert(x,num)
    x+=1
print("The elements are: ",a)

#duplicate elements
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    for j in range (i+1, len(a)):
        if(a[i]==a[j]):
            print("\nThe duplicate elements are: ",(a[j]))
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
for i in range(x, y):
   # Code to loop through here
```

Is essentially saying that you will loop through the loop code one time for every number i between x and y, including x and excluding y.

We can write an equivalent statement with a "while" loop. But we'll need to manage the variable i separately (including initializing it and incrementing it manually)

```
i = x
while i < y:
   # Code to loop through here
   i += 1
```

Now that you know how these 2 loop types are equivalent, you can use this equivalency to translate your code from a for loop to a while loop. You will need to do it twice; once for each for-loop in your code. I definitely recommend doing this on your own as it's an important part of the learning process!

Comment: Thank you! I really want to learn but I've been stuck for a long while now so my progress is kinda slow ;-;

Answer (score 0):

The concept is the same as for the `for-loop` ,only difference will be increasing the indexes manually since `while` is used for condition based `loops`.

```
sum = 0 #to add each duplicates value 
dup=[]  #store each duplicate if needed 

# increase the values of i,j manually 
i = 0
while(i< len(a)):
    j=i+1
    while(j<len(a)):
        if(a[i]==a[j]):
            #if duplicate found then add 
            sum = sum + a[i]
            dup.append(a[i])
        j=j+1
    i=i+1       
        

print("\nThe duplicate elements are: ",dup)
print("Sum of of the duplicates :" , sum)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with identifying the right duplicate elements, but I think that should be a problem on my part? nevertheless, thank you for the help! I understood the gist of the idea of how I should convert loops :>

Comment: My inputs are : `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6`
Output : 
`The duplicate elements are:  [1, 2]
Sum of of the duplicates : 3`

I hope this the intended behaviour you wanted .

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import any modules, Python's builtin list is sufficient for your application. Start with an empty `duplicates` list, `dup_sum = 0`, and go through all elements of your array; if some element is not in `duplicates` and its `count` is greater than `1`, insert it into `duplicates` and add the sum of occurrences to `dup_sum`. Finally, print the info. you want.

```
a = []
x = 0
# size of array
arrsize = int(input('Please Enter the number of elements: '))

# elements
print(f'Please Enter {arrsize} elements')
while x < arrsize:
    num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    a.append(num)
    x += 1
print(f'The elements are: {a}')

# duplicate elements
duplicates = []
dup_sum = 0
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    d = a[i]
    if d not in duplicates:
        dcount = a.count(d)
        if dcount > 1:
            dup_sum += d * dcount
            duplicates.append(d)
    i += 1
print(f'The duplicate elements are {duplicates}')
print(f'Sum of duplicates = {dup_sum}')
```

Here is a sample run of the program:

```
Please Enter the number of elements: 5
Please Enter 5 elements
Enter a number: 1
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 3
The elements are: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
The duplicate elements are [2, 3]
Sum of duplicates = 10
```